# How to delete a shared folder using c# code if the directory is opened on another machine?

Tags: c#, .net, shared-directory

I'm trying to delete an empty shared directory which is opened in another machine. 
If i directly delete the directory(right click and delete) it is removed.

```
Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
        st.Start();
 while(true){
            try
            {
                Directory.Delete(pathToDelete, true);
                Console.WriteLine("Directory Deleted" + "Elapsed time:" + st.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString() + "sec");
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if ((e is System.IO.IOException) || (e is System.UnauthorizedAccessException) ||
                    (e is System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    if (st.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Can not delete directory ");
                        return;
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

It is not deleting the directory if the directory opened on same machine or different machine using the shared-path.

[I found this](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/258411-removing-folder-share)
but i couldn't understand the code properly.

Anyone suggest a better method?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the string value for Path to Delete?

Comment: Is the app being run as an admin (if on Windows Vista or 7)? What exact exception is thrown?

Comment: I've used "C:\dir"   for the pathToDelete.  Shared Folder Path is "\\SPHVM-33821\dir"

Comment: The exception Thrown: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\dir' because it is
 being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\dir' because it is being used by another process

That means that its in use, therefore your not going to be able to remove it. If its empty like you say, then it must be either a) in use by someone on the Network Share or there's something running on the server that its ran from that's monitoring it. You may need to stop a service.

Comment: Even i open the directory (not the files) from another machine using shared path, I could manually delete it. (Right Click and Delete). That is why i thought there should be a method to delete the folder through code.